# Why does lsof interpret my variables incorrectly?

Tags: bash, function, variables, lsof

I'm trying to set up a loop to monitor a file being written by Apple Compressor.  Once the file is no longer being written, I'd like to change the name of the directory it's in.  However, when I feed a variable containing the filepath to `lsof` it comes out garbled.

For instance, `"/Users/leftright/Desktop/Output/${process##*/}_PROCESSING/"` stored as `$output` is interpreted by `lsof` as `DHt\x96?\x7f`.  I can't see anything in the `lsof` manpages to suggest why that's happening.  It's being called in a if/then statement inside a function.

```
#!/bin/bash

compressor() {
    filepath="$1"
    process="${filepath%.*}"
    output="/Users/leftright/Desktop/Output/${process##*/}_PROCESSING/"
    filename="${filepath##*/}"
    moving="${output}""${filepath##*/}"
    cleanname="${filename%.*}"
    final= "${output}""${cleanname}".mp4
    completed="/Users/leftright/Desktop/Output/${process##*/}_COMPLETED/${cleanname}.mp4"
    mkdir -m 777 "$output";
    mv "$filepath" "$moving";
    /Applications/Compressor.app/Contents/MacOS/Compressor -computergroup "This Computer" -jobpath "$output""$filename" -settingpath /Users/leftright/Documents/CONVERTHQTEST.cmprstng -locationpath "$final";
    while true; do
        if lsof "$final" > /dev/null; then
            sleep 1
        else
            mv "$final" "$completed"
        fi
    done
}
export -f compressor
fswatch -0 -v --event Created /Users/leftright/Desktop/Watch | xargs -0 -n1 -I filepath bash -c 'compressor "filepath"'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Thanks Cyrus! That's a really great resource. I've added it to my bookmarks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you playing at home, I left whitespace in front of `final= "${output}""${cleanname}".mp4` which caused it to be evaluated incorrectly.  Cyrus' suggestion of shellcheck.net found the issue.